# Get the product raw price for display (float) on WooCommerce cart page

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, price, dokan

I am using WooCommerce with Dokan plugin. I need to convert the string to a number so that I can use it for calculations *(this has to be easier than I am making it)*.

I need to use the line subtotal rather than the product price because the product price is pulling back the lowest variable product price instead of the the option they selected.

I have tried `ltrim()` and `substring()`, the number is correct but it's returning it formatted and I can't figure out how to get rid of the currency symbol ($) and make it as a float number.

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
   $product = $cart_item['data'];
   $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    /*?>Product ID:  <?php  echo $product_id,"<br>"; */
   $quantity=1;
   
    $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
    ?>Quantity:  <?php  echo $quantity,"<br>"; 
    
/*  $price = WC()->cart->get_product_price( $product );
    ?>Total Price 1:  <?php  echo $price,"<br>"; */
    
    //$price = get_post_meta($cart_item['product_id'] , '_price', true);
    
    $price = WC()->cart->get_product_price( $product );
    ?>Price:  <?php  echo $price,"<br>"; 
    
    $res = ltrim($price,12);

    ?>Price:  <?php  echo $res,"<br>"; 
    
    
    
    $item_total = $price * $quantity;    
    ?>Item Total:  <?php  echo $item_total,"<br>";
    

    
    $vendor_id = get_post($product_id); 
    /*?>Vendor ID: <?php echo $vendor_id->post_author,"<br>"; */
    $admin_commission  = get_user_meta( $vendor_id->post_author, 'dokan_admin_percentage', true );
   ?>Admin Commission: <?php echo $admin_commission, "<br>";
    $commission_amount = number_format(($price) * ( (get_user_meta( $vendor_id->post_author, 'dokan_admin_percentage', true ))/100),2);
    $commission_total = ($commission_amount/2);
    ?>Commission_Total: <?php echo $commission_total,"<br><br>";
    $amt_raised_for_cause= $amt_raised_for_cause + $commission_total ;
   // Anything related to $product, check $product tutorial
   //$meta = wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item );
 
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of `$price` value?

Comment: You should not rely on any information like prices from the front end as a user can alter the values if they want to.  If possible you should recalculate the price or have some indication of the exact item rather than rely on prices.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helpful, $price get only number value.

```
$amount = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $price ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using correct way to get the raw product price for display (float number). Now in your provided code, `$amt_raised_for_cause` is not defined…

Try the following revisited code instead:

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $product      = $cart_item['data']; // The WC_Product Object
    $product_id   = $cart_item['product_id']; // The product ID (Or the variable product ID)
    $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id']; // The variation product ID

    /*?>
    Product ID:  <?php  echo $product_id,"<br>";
    Variation ID:  <?php  echo $product_id,"<br>";
    */

    $quantity = $cart_item['quantity']; // The cart item quantity
    ?>Quantity:  <?php  echo $quantity,"<br>";

    // Display the formatted price html (for cart item)
    $price_html = WC()->cart->get_product_price( $product );
    ?>Price:  <?php  echo $price_html,"<br>";

    // Get the raw product price for display (including taxes if it's enabled)
    if ( WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
        $price = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product );
    } else {
        $price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product );
    }

    // Display the raw product price
    /* ?>Price (raw):  <?php  echo $price,"<br>"; */

    $item_total   = $price * $quantity;
    ?>Item Total:  <?php  echo $item_total,"<br>";

    $vendor_id    = get_post($product_id); // The dokan vendor ID
    /*?>Vendor ID: <?php echo $vendor_id->post_author,"<br>"; */

    $admin_commission  = get_user_meta( $vendor_id->post_author, 'dokan_admin_percentage', true );
   ?>Admin Commission: <?php echo $admin_commission, "<br>";

    $commission_amount = number_format( $price * ( $admin_commission / 100 ), 2 );
    $commission_total  = $commission_amount / 2;
    
    ?>Commission_Total: <?php echo $commission_total,"<br><br>";
    $amt_raised_for_cause = $amt_raised_for_cause + $commission_total; // <=== $amt_raised_for_cause NOT DEFINED
    
   // Anything related to $product, check $product tutorial
   //$meta = wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item );
}
```

Tested and works

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. Thank you also for commenting it to help me understand.